# Python Interpreter in PyCharm does not recognize gcloud project set changes

Tags: ubuntu, google-app-engine, google-api, pycharm, gcloud

i've some gcloud app engine projects. I can change projects in terminal with `gcloud config set project (project id)` it runs and i can deploy different projects or whatever.

But for example i use Speech-to-Tex API in one Project and on running my .py local i get this message in console

'PermissionDenied: 403 Cloud Speech-to-Text API has not been used in project ***** before or it is disabled. ...`

And the project number that is shown  (*****) is the number of another project, so not the project whats active and set in Terminal.

I use a venv in Pycharm Community and Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Are you using your useraccount or service account to run ?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue

1. Downloaded a service account
2. Set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to point to it

The detail of the error mentioned in the [link](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/error-messages)